# Test whether $n$ distinct balls are distributed uniformly into $m$ bins

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, multinomial-distribution, uniform-distribution

Suppose I have $m$ bins and $n\gg m$ balls, labelled $1,\dots,n$. The balls are placed into the bins with an unknown distribution.

I now want to verify that the balls are most likely distributed uniformly at random into the bins.
The best I could come up with is the following [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test) test:

1. Count the number of balls in each bin: $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_m)$
2. Assume null-hypothesis $H_0$: The number of balls in each bin is uniformly distributed
3. Calculate the significance probability (p-value) $p$ of observing $x$ assuming $H_0$ using the multinomial test
4. If $p < \epsilon$, reject $H_0$

---

The only thing I get from this in my understanding is:

I assume that a uniform distribution of the balls into the bins implies that the number of balls in each bin is also uniformly distributed.
Thus, if I have to reject $H_0$ then the balls are not distributed uniformly at random into the bins because that would imply $H_0$. However, I cannot assume a uniform distribution in case $H_0$ is not rejected.

Is there any way to assess that the observed distribution of balls is likely to occur (maybe a p-value greater than $1-\epsilon$?) when assuming a uniform distribution?
I thought about performing the multinomial test considering only the $k$ smallest balls for multiple $1\leq k\leq n$.

Moreover, the (exact) multinomial test is computationally very expensive, is there a faster method for this particular case (e.g. LLG, chi-squared)?

Comment: Your point 3. is underdefined, how do you calculate a p-value just from multinomial distribution? Same idea as in Fisher exact test? Why not chi-squared or the LL G-test? Do you have some preferred alternative? For instance (you mentioned looking only at the smallest bin counts) your alternative is that most bins have equal prob, but one (or a few) have much smaller, look at the smallest, or if one has higher probability, look at the highest counts?

Comment: Yes, you are right that I did not specify how to calculate the p-value, mostly because I do not know which method is preferred and if some methods are not applicable. What do you mean by "preferred alternative"? That I should define $H_0$ as this alternative and test whether I can reject it?

Comment: The chisquare test is known as a test which have power for testing the null against many different deviations from it, but if you have special interest in some specific alternative one might make a test which have higher power for those specific alternatives. If you have some such specific alternative hypothesis in mind (I asked because you mentioned using  extremes for the test), one could try to find such test, otherwise go for the chisq test, unless the sample ize is to small